# Empty records when using DataTable as Datasource in Telerik report table

Tags: c#, telerik

This is my source code:

```
public ReptDoc() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataTable table = GetTable();
    table1.DataSource = table;
}

private DataTable GetTable() {
    // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("السعر", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("العدد", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("اسم المادة", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("المبلغ الكلي", typeof(string));

    // Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add("1000", "22", "تبريد", "200000");
    table.Rows.Add("1000", "22", "تبريد", "200000");
    return table;
}
```

I'm binding DT to table1 using table1 datasource. In the output report I get two empty rows?

Comment: Bind the data set with the report page

Comment: I get a duplicate table with empty rows!

Comment: check any spaces comes or not in the name of the table of dataset,

Comment: No spaces i can find. I know that structure of telerik table is complex with groups and so on, but i need to know if this method works?

Comment: this is working for me. when i tried. datasourse is correctly binded.

Comment: Can you show me you source code please? Ive been working on this all day.

Comment: same code i used.. r u getting values in table object

Comment: No, Show me how you  
Bind the data set with the report page?

Comment: use this instead of table1.DataSource = table; put ---->. table1.Tables[0].Merge = table; by this code i got the answer

Comment: Error 1 'Telerik.Reporting.Table' does not contain a definition for 'Tables' and no extension method 'Tables' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Reporting.Table' could be found!

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/object-data-source-how-to-bind-to-data-set refer this also, u can find how to bind. this way i binded the dataset

Comment: sorry use dataset insted of datatable in the main part.

Comment: Not working, Same problem.

Comment: Did u check the code in the link i provide the same code i used to do it is working for me.